# how to save small video file in as3 AIR for android

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, file, video, air

i am trying to save a small video file that contains sound and 1 picture (not something too heavy) is it possible to do this in air for android ?
Thnx.

Comment: If you're just trying to save a file, no matter what format, you can use the File class. (http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/File.html)
If you're trying to make a video on runtime and then save it as a video with sound, it's a different matter.
Please be more specific what you need.

Comment: i am trying to make a video from an object on stage let's say i have a movieclip on stage that i would like to render as a video and save it to flv file

Comment: I'll be frank: you don't want to do this. If you can manage to create the video, you will have to deal with major performance issues while doing so. My last AIR app included an audio recorder and using any WAV encoder out there caused it to freeze for 2-3x the length of the recording. I ended up building the encode process into the record process to fix this, but it was still very slow. Additionally, you will not be able to save to the standard h.264 format due to licensing issues.